# character set issue in encryption key

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm migrating some legacy code from a PHP 5.1 RHEL4 install to PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu. There is an encryption routine in there using mcyrpt (cast-128/ctr) which has a key hardcoded in.  The function works (i.e. I can encrypt then decrypt) on the new server, but refuses to decrypt data previously encrypted on the old server.

After much testing I'm pretty sure this comes down to the hard coded key that was used which contains both a # (octothorp) and £ (pound sterling) symbol; I think the old server was treating them differently to the new server, so when I'm trying to decrypt legacy data, my keys are different.

So - I ran some code on the old server to give me the ord values for each character in the key, which returned 35 (#) & 163 (£) respectively.  Using these codes I attempted to build my key with chr(35) & chr(163) on new server, but no matter what I try I can't get chr(35) to output a #, just £.  Even echo "###" returns "£££".

For what it's worth - I'm running from command line, have tried default_charset = "utf-8" and iso-8859-1, tried setting character sets with mb_internal_encoding and  tried changing the encoding of the files themselves to match the encoding on the legacy server.

Update: I've checked bytecode of IV, encrypted data and key before decryption and both are identical on origin and new server.

Where could I go now?

Comment: Yes, sounds like charset issues. Difficult to tell the issue from a description though. Hexdump the original, then use literals `"\x23\xA5"` for reconstructing those strings.

Comment: Closer, but no cigar yet I'm afraid.  I hexdumped on origin server and got 23 & a3 for # & £; rebuilding the key from literals gave me slightly incorrect key, so I replaced \xa3 with \xc2\xa3 - now echo $key perfectly (visually) matched the key on the origin server.  Sadly though, decryption fails, so mcrypt must see a different set of bytes than hexdumping gives us.  I've tried manually setting  mb_internal_encoding to iso-8859-1 as on origin server, and utf-8 but didn't change things.

Comment: You shouldn't fiddle with `mb_*` at all methinks. mcrypt shouldn't concern itself with the charset. While `C2 A3` would indeed be the UTF-8 encoding of the Latin-1 pound sign; that's only suitable for page output. But a correct HTML printout does not necessarily make it suitable as cryptkey. You *do* want exact byte strings for that. -- And hopefully this isn't all about encrypted passwords(?)

Comment: If only it was as simple as encrypted passwords.. The routine on the old server nibbled at databases encrypting potentially sensitive fields in archives.  If worst comes to worst I can decrypt everything and re-encrypt with a less troublesome key, but when I started this particular journey 14 hours ago that seemed trickier than making the key work!

Comment: Update - I used the same key as generated from hex literals on the origin server overriding its original key in ascii, and decryption still works fine.  Perhaps this suggests the issue isn't in character encoding and lies with the way mcrypt is working on the new server?